# Converting a 2D curve into points for data storage

Tags: java, android, mathematics, curves, serialization

I’ve created an algorithm which converts any curve i.e. path into minimum number of points so that I can save it into a file or database.

The method is simple: it moves three points in equal steps and measures the angle between the lines these points form. If the angle is bigger than the tolerance then it creates a new cubic curve to that point. Then it moves the lines forward and measures the angle again…

For those who know Android **Path** Class - Note that the **dstPath** is a custom class, which records the points into an Array so I can save the points later, while the **srcPath** is the result of a Regions union and therefore has no key points for me to save.

The problem is that the circle does not look smooth as you can see in this image, produced by the code below, where the source path consists of a perfect circle and rectangle. I tried to change angle of tolerance and the steps length, but nothing helps. I wonder if you can suggest any improvement to this algorithm, or a different approach.

EDIT: I have now posted the entire code for those who use Android java, so they can easily try and experiment.

[image]

```
public class CurveSavePointsActivity extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(new CurveView(this));
    }

    class CurveView extends View{

        Path srcPath, dstPath;
        Paint srcPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        Paint dstPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        public CurveView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            srcPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            srcPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            srcPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
            srcPaint.setTextSize(20);

            dstPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            dstPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            dstPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
            dstPaint.setTextSize(20);

            srcPath = new Path();
            dstPath = new Path();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

            //make a circle path
            srcPath.addCircle(w/4, h/2, w/6 - 30, Direction.CW);

            //make a rectangle path
            Path rectPath = new Path();
            rectPath.addRect(new RectF(w/4, h/2 - w/16, w*0.5f, h/2 + w/16), Direction.CW);


            //create a path union of circle and rectangle paths
            RectF bounds = new RectF();
            srcPath.computeBounds(bounds, true);
            Region destReg = new Region();
            Region clip = new Region();
            clip.set(new Rect(0,0, w, h));
            destReg.setPath(srcPath, clip);
            Region srcReg = new Region();
            srcReg.setPath(rectPath, clip); 
            Region resultReg = new Region();
            resultReg.op(destReg, srcReg, Region.Op.UNION);
            if(!resultReg.isEmpty()){
                srcPath.reset();
                srcPath.addPath(resultReg.getBoundaryPath());
            }

            //extract a new path from the region boundary path
            extractOutlinePath();

            //shift the resulting path bottom left, so they can be compared
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postTranslate(10, 30);
            dstPath.transform(matrix);

        }

         @Override 
            public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
                super.onDraw(canvas);    
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                canvas.drawPath(srcPath, srcPaint);
                canvas.drawPath(dstPath, dstPaint);

                canvas.drawText("Source path", 40, 50, srcPaint);
                canvas.drawText("Destination path", 40, 100, dstPaint);
         }


         public void extractOutlinePath() {

             PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(srcPath, false); //get access to curve points

             float p0[] = {0f, 0f}; //current position of the new polygon
             float p1[] = {0f, 0f}; //beginning of the first line
             float p2[] = {0f, 0f}; //end of the first & the beginning of the second line
             float p3[] = {0f, 0f}; //end of the second line

             float pxStep = 5; //sampling step for extracting points
             float pxPlace  = 0; //current place on the curve for taking x,y coordinates
             float angleT = 5; //angle of tolerance

             double a1 = 0; //angle of the first line
             double a2 = 0; //angle of the second line

             pm.getPosTan(0, p0, null); //get the beginning x,y of the original curve into p0
             dstPath.moveTo(p0[0], p0[1]); //start new path from the beginning of the curve
             p1 = p0.clone(); //set start of the first line

             pm.getPosTan(pxStep, p2, null); //set end of the first line & the beginning of the second

             pxPlace = pxStep * 2;
             pm.getPosTan(pxPlace, p3, null); //set end of the second line


             while(pxPlace < pm.getLength()){
             a1 = 180 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(p1[1] - p2[1], p1[0] - p2[0])); //angle of the first line
             a2 = 180 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(p2[1] - p3[1], p2[0] - p3[0])); //angle of the second line

             //check the angle between the lines
             if (Math.abs(a1-a2) > angleT){

               //draw a straight line to the first point if the current p0 is not already there
               if(p0[0] != p1[0] && p0[1] != p1[1]) dstPath.quadTo((p0[0] + p1[0])/2, (p0[1] + p1[1])/2, p1[0], p1[1]);

               dstPath.quadTo(p2[0] , p2[1], p3[0], p3[1]); //create a curve to the third point through the second

               //shift the three points by two steps forward
               p0 = p3.clone();
               p1 = p3.clone();
               pxPlace += pxStep;
               pm.getPosTan(pxPlace, p2, null); 
               pxPlace += pxStep;
               pm.getPosTan(pxPlace, p3, null);
               if (pxPlace > pm.getLength()) break;
             }else{
               //shift three points by one step towards the end of the curve
               p1 = p2.clone(); 
               p2 = p3.clone();
               pxPlace += pxStep;
               pm.getPosTan(pxPlace, p3, null); 
             }
             }
             dstPath.close();
         }
    }

}
```

Here's a comparison between the original and what my algorithm produces:

[image: comparison between paths; noticeably smoother corners on the derivative]

Comment: why not use b-splines?

Comment: if you know the thing is a circle and a rectangle, why not store a circle and a rectangle?  And in generalized form - whatever input generated your thing is probably a reasonable format to store it in. If you are looking for a compression scheme that seems like a different question (or at least we'd need a lot more info about the source data to be helpful).

Comment: It can be any unpredicatable shape as I said in the first sentence - the circle and rectange here are only a test example.

Comment: @Lumis you really should look into b-splines, it what they're for. Any reason to try implement your own solution?

Comment: @Griffin - My entire finger drawing app is based on using Android Path Class, which is fast and has quad and cubic functions, so I am trying to find a solution using these features.

Comment: Well path class will construct those curves with splines so you're already using it. I have another suggestion,less math oriented: instead of saving points, save the user input (command pattern) and replay it to build the same "image".

Comment: @GriffinHeart that assumes these came from an appropriate source of discrete actions (user) instead of, say, geometry from an app that exported primitives.

Comment: Can you post rendered pictures of original srcPath and srcPath after resultReg.getBoundaryPath()? Preferably with stroke width 1 and antialiasing disabled.

Comment: @msell, see the image - source path is a result of getBoundaryPath(), destination is result of my path extracting algorithm. Intially I had a perfect circle and rectangle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have two problems:

## Non-symmetric control points

Initially you start with equal distances between p0 to p1 and p1 to p2. If the tolerance angle between the line segments is not met, you move p1 and p2 forward, but keep p0 where it was. This increases the distance between p0 to p1 while keeping the distance between p1 to p2 the same. When you create a curve using p1 as the control points, it can be heavily biased towards p2 depending on how many iterations have passed since the last curve. If you would move p2 twice the amount than p1, you would get even distances between the points.

## Quadratic curves

As mentioned in other answers as well, quadratic curve is not very good for this case. Adjacent curves you create should share a **control point and a tangent**. When your input data is just points, [Catmull-Rom Spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Catmull.E2.80.93Rom_spline) is a good choice for that purpose. It's a cubic Hermite curve, where the tangents for the control points are calculated from previous and next points.

The Path API in Android supports Bézier curves, which are a little different than Hermite curves regarding parameters. Fortunately Hermite curves can be converted to Bézier curves. [Here](http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/code%20repository/?get=Catmull-Rom-to-Bezier) is the first example code I found when Googling. [This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3559116/160539) also seems to give the formula.

You also mentioned the problem of sharp edges. With the input data you have, it's impossible to detect if there is an actual sharp corner or just a very steep curve. If this becomes a problem, you can make the iteration more adaptive by increasing / decreasing the step on-the-fly as needed.

**Edit:**
After further thinking quadratic curves could be used after all. Instead of drawing a quadratic curve from p0 to p2 using p1 as the control point, draw it from p0 to p1 using a new point p0_1 as the control points. See the picture below.
[image: New control points]

If p0_1 is in the intersection of the tangents in p0 and p1, the result should be smooth. Even better, since `PathMeasure.getPosTan()` returns also tangent as the third parameter, you can use actual accurate tangents instead of approximations from adjacent points. With this approach you need less changes to your existing solution.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2932601/160539), the intersection point can be calculated with the following formula:

```
getPosTan(pxPlace0, p0, t0); // Also get the tangent
getPosTan(pxPlace1, p1, t1);
t1 = -t1; // Reverse direction of second tangent
vec2 d = p1 - p0;
float det = t1.x * t0.y - t1.y * t0.x;
float u = (d.y * t1.x - d.x * t1.y) / det;
float v = (d.y * t0.x - d.x * t0.y) / det; // Not needed ... yet
p0_1 = p0 + u * t0;
```

This solution however works only if both u and v are non-negative. See the second picture:
[image: Rays don't intersect]

Here the rays don't intersect although the lines would, since u is negative. In this case it's not possible to draw a quadratic curve that would smoothly connect to the previous one. Here you need the bézier curves. You can calculate the control points for it either with the method given earlier in this answer or derive them directly from the tangents. Projecting p0 to the tangent ray p0+u*t0 and vise versa for the other ray gives both of the control points c0 and c1. You can also adjust the curve by using any point between p0 and c0 instead of c0 as long as it lies on the tangent ray.

**Edit2:** 
    If your drawing position is in p1, you can calculate the bezier control points to p2 with the following pseudo code:

```
vec2 p0, p1, p2, p3; // These are calculated with PathMeasure
vec2 cp1 = p1 + (p2 - p0) / 6;
vec2 cp2 = p2 - (p3 - p1) / 6;
```

With these you can append a path from p1 to p2:

```
path.cubicTo(cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, p2.x, p2.y);
```

Replace the vector operations with per component operations on float[[2](http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/code%20repository/?get=Catmull-Rom-to-Bezier)] arrays to match your code. You start by initializing `p1 = start;` and p2 and p3 are the next points. p0 is initially undefined. For the first segment where you don't have p0 yet, you can use a quadratic curve from p1 to p2 with cp2 as the control point. The same for the end of the path where you don't have p3, you can draw a quadratic curve from p1 to p2 with cp1 as the control point. Alternatively you can initialize p0=p1 for the first segment and p3=p2 for the last segment. After every segment you shift the values `p0 = p1; p1 = p2; and p2 = p3;` when moving forward.

When you are saving the path, you just save all points p0 ... pN. No need to save the control points cp1 and cp2, as they can be calculated as needed.

**Edit3:**
As it seems to be hard to get good input values for the curve generation, I propose another approach: Use serialization. Android Path doesn't seem to support it, but fortunately Region class does. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13393533/160539) for the code. This should give you the exact result. It might take some space in the serialized form if it's not optimized, but in that case it should compress very well. Compression is easy in Android Java using [GZIPOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html).

Comment: That sounds promising. However it is not p0 but p1,p2,p3 that are used, p0 is only for storing new definite points when they are calculated and for the sake of straight lines, so that they are not sampled each step. Can you help me how to calculate x,y for new control points?

Comment: I could do that later, but meanwhile check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931573/determining-if-two-rays-intersect. With u and v you can get the intersection point.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I would like to try this, but it needs to be writen in Java for Android. There is no vector2 and t1 and p1 etc are float arrays so I cannot do any direct operation on them like t1 = -t1, or u*t0. I assume that t1 = -t1 means t1.x = -t1x; t1.y = -t1.y etc, right?

Comment: Yes, that was just pseudo code to make it more compact and readable.

Comment: Well, the plot is thickening. Because the region intersection of two paths in Android returns a path which is NOT anti-aliased, the tangents are over the place. So the proper solution would be to drive some smooth curve through the given points first and then sample it. Your code works perfectly fine on an anti-aliased path, it produces proper control points.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Antialiasing is a concept related to rendering, not a property of a path. If you mean that for intersections the PathMeasure class returns points with integer coordinates and that messes up the tangents, then I suggest using my initial suggestion with Catmull-Rom splines. This is effectively the "some smooth curve through the given points" you are looking for, except that you can just store the spline curves directly instead of sampling it. It's also a good investment for future to learn Catmull-Rom splines, as they are very useful in game development.

Comment: When I try to combine paths, like have a union of circle and square, then Android seems to convert them into bitmap regions first, creates a union and then converts it back into an non antialiased path i.e. a path with small steps on its curved parts. If it was just one curve then yes I could use splines, but for a complex shape which combines curves and straight simple shapes, I don't think I can just draw a spline through the given points from pathMeasure. The algorithm would have to distinguish between straight lines and curves.

Comment: But isn't this what you are doing anyway? I didn't see anything that would distinguish straight lines from curves in the code you provided. My suggestion is to use cubic splines instead of quadratic ones to make it continuous. If you could detect straight lines, you could draw those as easily with cubic lines than with quadratic.

Comment: I am not very good in converting some abstract math to java code. Can you suggest some code which would calculate a spline point from the points I get from pathMeasure. Then, as you said I could convert these points into android quads so I can easily reload the path from a file.

Comment: Okay, I added explanation and code for calculating Bézier control points.

Comment: Because the rest of my app is using one control point, can you post a solution with the one control point as well for quadTo. I can then see what works best for me. By the way thank for making this effort, you definitely deserve the points!

Comment: Also because the points p0-p3 are chaotically placed around the curve I don't think the cubicTo or quadTo should use any of them as a point through which the line should pass.

Comment: Added one more idea using Region serialization.

Answer (score 13):

## What would the W3C do?

The internet has had this problem. The [World Wide Web Consortium](http://www.w3.org/) noticed. It has a **recommended standard solution** since 1999: [Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). It's an [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)-based file format specifically designed for storing 2D shapes.

## "*Scalable-what?*"

**Scalable Vector Graphics**!

- **Scalable**: It's meant to scale smoothly to any size.
- **Vector**: It's based on the mathematical notion of [vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector).
- **Graphics**. It's meant to make pictures.

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/)'s the technical specification for SVG version 1.1.

<sup>(Don't be scared by the name; It's actually pleasant to read.)</sup>

They've written down exactly how [basic shapes](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/shapes.html) like [circles](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/shapes.html#CircleElement) or [rectangles](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/shapes.html#RectElement) are to be stored. For example, rectangles have these properties: `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`, `rx`, `ry`. (The `rx` and `ry` can be used for rounded corners.)

Here's their example rectangle in SVG: (Well, two really -- one for the canvas outline.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="12cm" height="4cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 400"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <desc>Example rect01 - rectangle with sharp corners</desc>

  <!-- Show outline of canvas using 'rect' element -->
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="1198" height="398"
        fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"/>

  <rect x="400" y="100" width="400" height="200"
        fill="yellow" stroke="navy" stroke-width="10"  />
</svg>
```

Here's what it represents:

[image: a yellow rectangle with a blue outline]

As the specification says, you're free to leave out some of the properties if you don't need them. (For example, `rx` and `ry` attributes weren't used here.) Yes, there's a ton of cruft at the top about `DOCTYPE` which you won't need just for your game. They're are optional too.

## Paths

SVG [paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html) are "paths" in the sense that if you *put a pencil to a paper, move it around and eventually raise it again*, you have a path. They don't *have* to be *closed*, but they might be.

Each path has a `d` attribute (I like to think it stands for "draw"), containing [path data](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathData), a sequence of **commands** for basically just *putting a pen to a paper and moving it around*.

They give the example of a triangle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="4cm" height="4cm" viewBox="0 0 400 400"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <title>Example triangle01- simple example of a 'path'</title>
  <desc>A path that draws a triangle</desc>
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="398" height="398"
        fill="none" stroke="blue" />
  <path d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z"
        fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
```

[image: a red triangle]

See the `d` attribute in the `path`?

```
d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z"
```

The `M` is a **command** for *Move to* (followed by coordinates), the `L`s are for *Line to* (with coordinates) and `z` is a command to close the path (i.e. draw a line back to the first location; that doesn't need coordinates).

Straight lines are boring? Use the [cubic](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands) or [quadratic](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataQuadraticBezierCommands) Bézier commands!

[image: some cubic Béziers]

The theory behind Bézier curves is covered well elsewhere (such as [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)), but here's the executive summary: Béziers have a start and end point, with possibly many control points that influence where the curve in between is going.

[image: tracing a quadratic Bézier]

The specification also gives instructions for converting most basic shapes into paths in case you want to.

## Why and when to use SVG

Decide carefully if you want to go down this path (pun intended), because it's really quite complicated to represent any arbitrary 2D shape in text! You can make your life so much easier if you e.g. limit yourself to just paths made of (potentially really many) straight lines.

But if you do decide you want arbitrary shapes, SVG is the way to go: It has great tool support: You can find [many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:XML_parsers) libraries for XML parsing at the low level and [SVG editor tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_vector_graphics_editors) at the high level.

Regardless, the SVG standard sets a good example.

Comment: The question is about converting a curve into points, not saving it. But thank you for this reference, it is good to know about SVG standard.

Comment: @Lumis The title and content would suggest otherwise. Consider rephrasing the question. (Or, now that this one is quite established, asking another one.)

Answer (score 4):

Your code contains a misleading comment:

```
dstPath.quadTo(p2[0] , p2[1], p3[0], p3[1]); //create a curve to the third point through the second
```

A quadratic bezier curve does *not* go *through* the second point. If you want to go through the second point you need a different type of curve, such as a [hermite curve](http://cubic.org/docs/hermite.htm). You may be able to convert the hermite curves into beziers so that you can use the Path class.

Another suggestion is instead of sampling the points, use the mean of the points you're skipping over.

Another suggestion is instead of using an angle as a threshold, use the difference between the actual curve and the approximate curve. Angles aren't the real problem; the real problem is when the set of points doesn't fit a bezier curve.

Another suggestion is to use cubic beziers, with the tangent of one matching the tangent of the next. Otherwise (with quadratics) I think your curves won't match up smoothly.

Comment: You are right, the second point only "pulls" the curve towards it. The cubicTo requires two control points instead of one as the quadTo. The problem is of course how to get right control points. Note that I don't want to lose sharp corners as the source Path can be a combination of any shape straight or round - basically I am making an image selection tool where I can save the selected path.

Answer (score 4):

To get a smoother intersection of two paths, you could scale them up before intersection and scale them down after.

I don't know if it's a good solution, but it worked well for me. It's also fast. In my example, I intersect a rounded path with a pattern I created (stripes). It looks good even when scaled.

Here my code:

```
    Path mypath=new Path(<desiredpath to fill with a pattern>);
    String sPatternType=cpath.getsPattern();

    Path pathtempforbounds=new Path(cpath.getPath());
    RectF rectF = new RectF();
     if (sPatternType.equals("1")){
         turnPath(pathtempforbounds, -45);
     }
     pathtempforbounds.computeBounds(rectF, true);

     float ftop=rectF.top;
     float fbottom=rectF.bottom;
     float fleft=rectF.left;
     float fright=rectF.right;
     float xlength=fright-fleft;

     Path pathpattern=new Path();

     float ypos=ftop;
     float xpos=fleft;

     float fStreifenbreite=4f;

     while(ypos<fbottom){
         pathpattern.moveTo(xpos,ypos);
         xpos=xpos+xlength;
         pathpattern.lineTo(xpos, ypos);
         ypos=ypos+fStreifenbreite;
         pathpattern.lineTo(xpos, ypos);
         xpos=xpos-xlength;
         pathpattern.lineTo(xpos, ypos);
         ypos=ypos-fStreifenbreite;
         pathpattern.lineTo(xpos, ypos);
         pathpattern.close();
         ypos=ypos+2*fStreifenbreite;

     }

     // Original vergrössern

     scalepath(pathpattern,10);
     scalepath(mypath,10);

     if (sPatternType.equals("1")){
         Matrix mdrehen=new Matrix();
         RectF bounds=new RectF();
         pathpattern.computeBounds(bounds, true);
         mdrehen.postRotate(45, (bounds.right + bounds.left)/2,(bounds.bottom + bounds.top)/2);
         pathpattern.transform(mdrehen);
     }

     RectF rectF2 = new RectF();
     mypath.computeBounds(rectF2, true);

     Region clip = new Region();
     clip.set((int)(rectF2.left-100f),(int)(rectF2.top -100f), (int)(rectF2.right+100f),(int)( rectF2.bottom+100f));
     Region region1 = new Region();
     region1.setPath(pathpattern, clip);

     Region region2 = new Region();
     region2.setPath(mypath, clip);

     region1.op(region2, Region.Op.INTERSECT);


     Path pnew=region1.getBoundaryPath();


     scalepath(pnew, 0.1f);
     cpath.setPathpattern(pnew);




public void turnPath(Path p,int idegree){
     Matrix mdrehen=new Matrix();
     RectF bounds=new RectF();
     p.computeBounds(bounds, true);
     mdrehen.postRotate(idegree, (bounds.right + bounds.left)/2,(bounds.bottom + bounds.top)/2);
     p.transform(mdrehen);
}

public void scalepath(Path p,float fscale){
     Matrix mverkleinern=new Matrix();
     mverkleinern.preScale(fscale,fscale);
     p.transform(mverkleinern);
}
```

[image]

Looks still smooth when zooming with canvas.scale():
[image]

Comment: Thanks to who ever spent me 10 reputation to add the images :-)

Comment: Amazingly, this simple trick solves two problems: firstly it makes the resulting path of intersection or union smooth and secondly my code in the question when sampling this same scaled-up path produces a perfectly smooth result. What an unexpected and simple solution, thank you!

Comment: @user Editing is free. For <2k-rep users, it's actually a +2.

Comment: @Lumis I'm a little confused -- I thought you asked how to *store* paths?

Comment: Unfortunately, after more testing I've found that because Region uses pixels which the path would occupy when drawn, the app easily runs out of memory if the scaling of the Path is big and done repeatedly. So this solution is limited & risky, but good to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Look at polygon interpolation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation)

Basically, you take n equispaced nodes (optimal interpolation is not equispaced, but for your case it should be good enough and easy to implement)

You end up with a polygon of order n which decreases the error between your curve **if** (<-- big if) your line is **smooth** enough.

In your case, you're doing **linear** (order 1) interpolation.

The other case (as *GriffinHeart* recommended) was to use Splines (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation)

Either case would give you some form of polynomial **fit** for your curve.

Answer (score 2):

If the point of the conversion is for storage only, and when you render it back on the screen you need it to be smooth, then the highest fidelity storage you can get, while still minimizing the total storage required to persist a given curve might be to actually store the attributes of the circle (or an arc, rather) and re-draw it on demand.

Origin. Radius. Start/stop angles for drawing the arc.

If you need to convert the circle/arc into points anyway for rendering, then you can possibly to that upon loading it from storage, while always storing just the attributes.

Comment: The source path/curve can be any shape including a drawing of a free line. I have been considering that solution which would have to save each component separately and then combine them when loaded but it requires a great amount of work and it would slow down manipulation of such a complex object as every transformation would have to be applied to each of its components in order to be able to save it again.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason for going for curves as opposed to straight lines? Straight lines are simpler to work with, and can be rendered efficiently in hardware.

The other approach worth considering is to store a couple of bits per pixel, stating if it's inside, outside or on the outline of the shape. This should compress well, and might be more efficient than lines for complex selections.

You might also find these articles interesting / useful:

- http://blog.getpaint.net/2008/06/02/whats-coming-in-paintnet-v335/ (bottom half)
- http://blog.getpaint.net/2009/02/25/introducing-paintnet-v35%E2%80%99s-new-selection-renderer/
- http://blog.getpaint.net/2011/12/04/responsive-selection-rendering-for-paint-net-4-0/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at curve interpolation - there's a few different types you can implement that will help smooth your curve. The more points you can get on that circle, the better. Storage is pretty cheap - so if extracting 360 close nodes is cheap enough (even at 8 bytes for position; 360 nodes is hardly expensive to store).

You can place with some interpolation samples [here](http://staff.www.ltu.se/~peppar/presentations/bibdc961114/misc_applets/ParamCurve/) with only four points; and the results are quite good (my favourite is the Bezier for this case, although others might chime in about other effective solutions).

You can play around in [here](http://www.theparticle.com/applets/nyu/BezierApplet/), too.